# Why does typescript compiler doesn't type check null value with generic interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have this custom hook I created with react `useState` hook.

```
export interface IUseValuedState<T> {
    value: T;
    setState: (value: T) => void;
    isExist: boolean;
}


export function useValuedState<T>(initialValue: T): IUseValuedState<T> {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(initialValue);

    const setState = (value: T) => {
        setValue(value);
    };

    const isValueExist = value !== null && value !== undefined;

    return {
        value: value,
        setState: setState,
        isExist: isValueExist,
    };
}
```

If I try to do something like

```
const something = useValuedState<Something[] | null>(null)

function foo(){
  if (!something) return "something is null"
  if (!something.value) return "something value is null"
  if (!something.isExist) return "something is null"

   // This should be Something[], but I keep getting something[] | null
  return something

}
```

Typescript compiler doesn't know it's not null, any idea why ?

Comment: You have defined a function that takes one type parameter, but you are passing it two. [That should not even compile](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACgB4BciGAlEQIZgCeiA3gL4BQjECAzlIgEbkBOiAXmSo0YEAFsuAU14AaRB14wwAc1wBWEgG5GQA).

Comment: @JaredSmith I made a mistake as Nicholas Tower pointed  , I corrected it now

Answer (score 1):

> Typescript compiler doesn't know it's not null, any idea why ?

Yes, because it has type `T` and you told the compiler the type of `T` is `Something[] | null`. If you don't want that, you can change how it's typed:

```
export interface IUseValuedState<T> {
    value: T | null;
    setState: (value: T) => void;
    isExist: boolean;
}

export function useValuedState<T>(initialValue: T | null): IUseValuedState<T> {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<T | null>(initialValue);

    const setState = (value: T) => {
        setValue(value);
    };

    const isValueExist = value !== null && value !== undefined;

    return {
        value: value,
        setState: setState,
        isExist: isValueExist,
    };
}

const something = useValuedState<Something[]>(null)

function foo(){
  if (!something) return "something is null"
  if (!something.value) return "something value is null"
  if (!something.isExist) return "something is null"

  return something.value;

}

const bar = foo(); // Something[] | "something is null"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAORTo4DGMVA3AFCvAB2+UJDBmCuhgALLgHNEhNq3QAPSLDhcefegQCSAVQwA1HABtk6ACbY86ADwAVAHyJWcJ3ABuh4wC441uAB84nMgGBmzOcBgw5vheABRuRuhe1gCUcAC89i4QwCahzsCoAKJyBTBeAEYQEAZ0nGyE7PKK8CTInIzAEJwoeu6mUVZ2MVzAMMCG+glJfgFBBsle2r0JZrj4NvYIjs70XajwANrxxgA04cKTxgC66T1Ya4MzgcG2w5yj4waX6MkyYbucfbnSIPW5xPpJVIZBxhMIRb7ghK-bZOaTsf57eAFb7FUq3Y4EACEaTSs2CcAAZBTXH04MTSW0TOgSFxTH9nLQYMgoN0trDnASvASTijYREBl5xQ8RfynAVcfsvNi+gqYDLnGiGqwAUDUEJRBJbmh0N9VhZLIIQMIxJxxAcrq9nvN2K12mMuqQqjFknzlCQ4DFCXqrQbbalOdzugAiYPWw0FMkGKPbYD+wOx0PiAB0BPDwkjcBj+ptkgJylQieTcrTQeLEiz8pK+zzXJ5hYzJfLlfRcAjbY79YJMi1Ovg5RwUFuJC9yKAA)

Comment: That will complain that `Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type Something[]`, don't know why it's not showing in playground

Comment: @AbdulrahimIliasuIllo there is only one place you pass an argument of null: the call to `useValuedState`. If you don't change the function signature like I have (`useValuedState<T>(initialValue: T | null): IUseValuedState<T>`), you'll see that error. If you do, you won't.